# Creating a racket function that creates 2 rackets for ping-pong game in python

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a function that creates 2 rackets that move independent of one another.
I have created a racket class which is supposed to control all racket functionality for my python ping-pong game.

The issue is, the way I've written the code, is in such a way that the left racket movement overrides the right rackets' movement. The left racket is supposed to move up and down, while the right racket is supposed to be moved by keyboard commands (I reference the right_racket_up_move & right_racket_up_down functions in my main.py). What happens is that the left racket moves up and down to the ends of the screen (as it should), however, it also moves when I click the keyboard commands, which it shouldn't. The right racket remains stationary.
Please see the code I have written.

```
from turtle import Turtle

left_racket_pos = [(-385, 225), (-385, 245), (-385, 265), (-385, 285)]
left_racket_x_cor = -385
right_racket_pos = [(380, 225), (380, 245), (380, 265), (380, 285)]
right_racket_x_cor = 380
up = 90
down = 270

full_racket = []


def create_racket(position):
    racket_addition = Turtle()
    racket_addition.penup()
    racket_addition.shape("square")
    racket_addition.color("white")
    racket_addition.goto(position)
    full_racket.append(racket_addition)
    return full_racket


class Racket(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.racket_left = []
        self.racket_right = []
        self.racket_left_head = self.complete_racket_left()[0][0]
        self.racket_right_head = self.complete_racket_right()[0][0]
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def complete_racket_left(self):
        for count in left_racket_pos:
            self.racket_left.append(create_racket(count))
        return self.racket_left

    def complete_racket_right(self):
        for pos in right_racket_pos:
            self.racket_right.append(create_racket(pos))
        return self.racket_right

    def racket_movement(self):
        for i in range(len(self.racket_left) - 1, 0, -1):
            new_y = self.racket_left[0][i - 1].ycor()
            self.racket_left[0][i].goto(left_racket_x_cor, new_y)
        self.racket_left_head.forward(21)

    def racket_down_move(self):
        self.racket_left_head.setheading(down)
        self.racket_movement()

    def racket_up_move(self):
        self.racket_left_head.setheading(up)
        self.racket_movement()

    def racket_move_up_down(self):
        if self.x < 24:
            self.racket_down_move()
            self.x += 1
        if self.x >= 24 and self.y < 27:
            self.racket_up_move()
            self.y += 1
        if self.y == 27:
            self.y = 0
            self.x = -3

    def right_racket_up_move(self):
        self.racket_right_head.setheading(up)
        self.racket_right_head.forward(10)

    def right_racket_down_move(self):
        self.racket_right_head.setheading(down)
        self.racket_right_head.forward(10)
```

I was hoping the rackets will move in the stipulated manner

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: How do I write code, or what should I change in my code to allow the right racket to move on Keyboard commands and not the left racket? I'm hoping this is clear

Comment: please edit your post ... add the question there ... this site is not a forum ... all information belongs in the question at the top of this page

Comment: the `class Racket` should not have code for both left and right rackets ... it should have code for the `size` and `position` of a racket, and possibly code for optional autonomous motion ... right now, you have one racket that consists of two paddles ... you need to have two rackets, each one consisting of one paddle

Comment: Thank you for that, will do as advised and keep you posted.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it and it worked